# AngularJS ngRepeat sluggish display behavior on clearing bulk data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I created a table with `ng-repeat` on `tr` elements with 1.000 records.
When I filter down the table element by changing the item on which the `ng-repeat` is bind to, there is a strange behavior when clearing the table.

For the purpose of this question, I have minimized my call to its simplest expression.

This is my `Typescript` code loading 1.000 data when clicking on button load and loading only 1 record when clicking on the reset button.

```
SearchFilters = () => {
    this.dataSEJLABELCurrent = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        this.dataSEJLABELCurrent.push({ SEJCOD: "sej" + i, ADMDAT: "19650521", ADMHEU: "72800", SORDAT: "19650521", SORHEU: "72800", PATCOD: "35", PATPRE: "j" + i, PATNOM: "n" + i, NAIDAT: "19650521" });
    }
}

ResetFilters = () => {
    var i = 0;
    this.dataSEJLABELCurrent=[{ SEJCOD: "sej" + i, ADMDAT: "19650521", ADMHEU: "72800", SORDAT: "19650521", SORHEU: "72800", PATCOD: "35", PATPRE: "j" + i, PATNOM: "n" + i, NAIDAT: "19650521" }];

}
```

This is my HTML page with `ng-repeat`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.dataSEJLABELCurrent" class="pointer shadow hover">
        <td>{{::item.SEJCOD}}</td>
        <td>{{item.ADMDAT}}  {{item.ADMHEU}}</td>
        <td>{{item.SORDAT}}  {{item.SORHEU}}</td>
        <td>{{::item.PATCOD}}</td>
        <td>{{::item.PATPRE}}</td>
        <td>{{::item.PATNOM}}</td>
        <td>{{item.NAIDAT}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What visually happen when I click on filter button is:

1. My newly pushed record is displayed on top of the current records on the screen.
2. There is now 1000 + 1 records in the HTML table.
3. Every other (previous) records are getting deleted one by one during 2 seconds.
4. At some point, all the original 1.000 records will be deleted leaving the new record as expected.

It looks like every operation I add on the records HTML side are slowing, even more, the display behavior from what I saw every of the following operation is slowing the process:

1. Adding a new property to display (even duplicating the same like displaying 10 times the `SEJCOD` for instance).
2. Adding a function for instance `vm.formatOwnDate(item.ADMDAT)` instead of `item.ADMDAT`.
3. Adding `ui-sref="sejlabel({sejcod:'{{item.SEJCOD}}'})"` on the tr element.

I don't understand why this behavior is only appearing on the clear and not on the show data too?

This is a `gif` of the behavior: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Q80.jpg (click on it to get it full screen).

Updating `ng-repeat` model from 1.000 to 1 record create a strange behavior like it is purging the records from the screen for 2 seconds like it has a lot of jobs to do, but updating from 1 to 1.000 is instant.

Comment: Guessing this has to do with rendering the new view without 1000 records versus having a view already with the 1000 records and adding just 1 more.

Comment: 1000 bindings is really gonna crash your system, angular is not made for that. I suggest you use pagination or something.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.
I have ngAnimate module in my app, which is applying his own class when my table is getting cleared.
With these clases, it add a fade effect transition in CSS.

I needed to prevent the ngAnimate behavior on my table :

```
.no-animate * {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
```

and

```
<table class="table no-animate">
```

Comment: congrats on finding. Btw here's the meat action https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L510. For further speed optimisation you can apply `track by` to `ng-repeat` and also move from `{{}}` to `ng-bind=""` style, it should increase watching performance for more than 2 times, [DETAILS](http://www.codelord.net/2017/03/23/the-performance-difference-between-ng-bind-and-%7B%7B%7D%7D/).

Answer (score 0):

Use track by feature of ng-repeat. That should solve your issue.

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">
  {{n}}
</div>
```

You can track by $index or by any unique Id.

For more details check: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat